# Apply more than one filters in elastic search nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to apply more than one filter on nested object and I want to return only document which has all matching in single object not from multiple object.

Data in elastic search

```
D1 document
"fields":[
{
    "field_name": "test",
    "field_value": "test",
    "field_id": "123"
},
{
    "field_name": "test1",
    "field_value": "test1",
    "field_id": "1231"
},
{
    "field_name": "test2",
    "field_value": "test2",
    "field_id": "1232"
}]

D2 document
"fields":[
{
    "field_name": "test1",
    "field_value": "testda",
    "field_id": "123a"
},
{
    "field_name": "test1ad",
    "field_value": "test1",
    "field_id": "1231"
},
{
    "field_name": "test2a",
    "field_value": "test2a",
    "field_id": "1231"
}]
```

Fields is nested object with text & keyword mapping

```
"fields": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "field_id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "field_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "field_value": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

This is my elastic search query

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested":{
          "path":"fields",
          "query":{
            "bool":{
              "must":{
                "bool":{
                  "must":[{
                    "match":{
                      "field_id.raw": "1231"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match":{
                      "field_value.raw": "test1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match":{
                      "field_name.raw": "test1"
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not getting any response.
And I want only first document to return as it has matching in same object not document 2 which also have match that is here and there.
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use fully qualified name in case of nested fields. So instead of `field_id.raw` it should be `fields.field_id.raw`. Same goes for other fields as well.

So your query should be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "fields",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "fields.field_id.raw": "1231"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "fields.field_value.raw": "test1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "fields.field_name.raw": "test1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and if I want to apply should also same time then ??

Comment: For nested field(s) ?